# Duration calculation and control in ROS - furthermore why does this script keep running even after pressing Ctrl-C?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, python2.7, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I have written some code to make the turtlebot turn around. The code is working. What I want to know is how fast the turtlebot is running  and how I can control it. Forexample, how can I ensure that the turtlebot turns 5 degrees in one minute?
Last part of the question. After pressing Ctrl-C, the turtlebot stops but the script keeps running. Why? and how can I stop that?

[this post](https://answers.ros.org/question/294440/ros-python-script-is-not-exiting-after-ctrl-c/)  does not really help.

went through  [this post](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time#Time_and_Duration) .Does that mean that the ***while*** loop below runs 5 times a second regardless of the values I put in the ***for*** loops? Or does it mean ROS tries its best to make sure that the loop runs 5 times a second to the best of  my machine's ability?
Thank you very much.

```
# 5 HZ
    angle = 5
    r = rospy.Rate(5);
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        # code to turn
        for x in range(0,100):
            rospy.loginfo("turn")
            turn_cmd.angular.z = radians(angle) 
            new_angle = (angle + new_angle) % 360
            self.cmd_vel.publish(turn_cmd)
            r.sleep()
         # code to pause  
        for x in range(0,100):
            rospy.loginfo("stop")
            turn_cmd.angular.z = radians(0)
            self.cmd_vel.publish(turn_cmd)

            r.sleep()

def shutdown(self):
    # stop turtlebot
    rospy.loginfo("Stop turning")
    self.cmd_vel.publish(Twist())
    rospy.sleep(1)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358095/duration-calculation-and-control-in-ros---furthermore-why-does-this-script-keep-running-even-after-pressing-ctrl-c?/) by [lxg](https://answers.ros.org/users/37572/lxg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rospy.Rate convenience class makes a best effort to maintain the loop running at the specified frequency by considering the execution time of the loop since the last successful r.sleep(). This means, in my case: and assuming I had one `r.sleep()` call, as long as the code execution time within the loop does not exceed 1/5 seconds, rospy.Rate will make sure the loop runs at 5Hz.
The script's continued execution has nothing to do with it. But for those who are curious, it was because when pressing `Ctrl-C: KeyboardInterrupt` will be handled differently than in normal Python scripts when using rospy.
I had to manually shutdown the script.
For details check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63205076/duration-calculation-and-control-in-ros-furthermore-why-does-this-script-keep)

---

Originally posted by [lxg](https://answers.ros.org/users/37572/lxg/) with karma: 11 on 2020-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0